# Building an array of values from Jsonb column data and querying records using that array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I'm working with a `subscriptions` and `plans` tables. The `subscriptions` table has a `product_quantity` column and the `plans` table has a jsonb column called `product_quantities_config` that  stores data in the following format `{min: 0, step: 1, max: 10}`.

Given the example above, would it be posible to transform the jsonb column data into an array of values starting from the `min` value up to the `max` value to end up with something like `[0, 1, 2 .. 10]` ?

I need to build a query to find all `subscriptions` where the `product_quantity` is not within the plans `product_quantities_config` boundaries, but I don't know how to transform the `plans.product_quantity_config` jsonb data into an array of values in Postgres (if it's even possible).

I suppose I'd then use that array of values as a subquery to find all subscriptions with a product_quantity `NOT IN` the given array of values.

Comment: How are the the tables related? On which columns can you join plans and subscriptions?  Can you please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a `cross join` statement to get a table of all values ​​from jsonb, after which you can write a `where product_quantity not in` condition for the product table

```
select * from subscriptions where product_quantity not in (select  value::int  from plans  cross join jsonb_each_text(product_quantities_config))
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3ce3981884bde50ced1df47c1ecdf686)

Comment: Thanks. The DBfiddle seems to work, but I don't understand how really. I see you are fetching the configuration values from the hash using `jsonb_each_text`. But then in the final query I can't tell how these values are used to fetch the correct Plan, which in your example has a `product_quantity` between `min` and `max` values but not a `step` value (as 7 (`min`) + 8 (`step`) can never be 12 (`product_quantity`).

Would you mind clearing that out for me? Otherwise thanks for the response.

Comment: @pinkfloyd90 Perhaps I misunderstood the question. Do you need to exclude subscriptions if product_quantity is between min and max? Or exclude subscriptions if product_quantity is equal to one of the jsonb values

Comment: @pinkfloyd90 Currently, the answer excludes all `subscriptions` if the `product_quantity` is equal to at least one value from jsonb

Comment: I need to find subscriptions with a `product_quantity` that is below the `min` configuration, above the `max` configuration or with a value that is not a `step` value. In your example, it seemed to work since the result includes a subscription with a value between `min` (7) and `max` (15) but 12 is not `step` value (if `min` is 7, `max` is 15 and `step` is 8, valid values would be 7 and 15). Hope it's more clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to build an array.

It's unclear to me how the two table are related, but may something like this might do what you want:

```
select s.*
from subscriptions s
where not exists (select *
                  from plans
                  where s.product_quantity between (product_quantities_config ->> 'min')::int
                                               and (product_quantities_config ->> 'max')::int)
```